# Ansible running one command out of many locally in a loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, ansible-2.x

Background,

I'm trying to create a loop that iterates over hash read from qa.yml file and for every user in the list it tries to find a file on the local server (public key), once the file is found it creates the user on remote machine and copies the public key to authorized_key on remote machine.

I'm trying to implement it in a way of iteration, so in order to update the keys or add more users keys I need to change the .yml list and place the public key file in the proper place. However I can't get the local_action + find working.

```
---
- hosts: tag_Ansible_CLOUD_QA

  vars_files:
    - ../users/qa.yml
    - ../users/groups.yml
  remote_user: ec2-user
  sudo: yes

  tasks:

  - name: Create groups
    group: name="{{ item.key }}" state=present
    with_dict: "{{ user_groups }}"

  - name: Create remote users QA
    user: name="{{ item.key }}" comment="user" group=users groups="qa"
    with_dict: "{{ qa_users }}"

  - name: Erase previous authorized keys QA
    shell: rm -rf /home/"{{ item.key }}"/.ssh/authorized_keys
    with_dict: "{{ qa_users }}"

  - name: Add public keys to remote users QA
    local_action:
      find: paths="{{'/opt/pubkeys/2016/q2/'}}" patterns="{{ item.key }}"
      register: result
    authorized_key: user="{{ item.key }}" key="{{ lookup('file', result) }}"
    with_dict: "{{ qa_users }}"
```

Hash:

```
qa_users:
  user1:
    name: User 1
  user2:
    name: User 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're cramming two tasks into a single task item in that final task so Ansible isn't going to like that.

Splitting the task properly should work:

```
  - name: Find keys
    local_action: find paths="{{'/opt/pubkeys/2016/q2/'}}" patterns="{{ item.key }}"
    register: result
    with_dict: "{{ qa_users }}"

  - name: Add public keys to remote users QA
    authorized_key: user="{{ item.0.key }}" key="{{ lookup('file', item.1.stdout) }}"
    with_together:
      - "{{ qa_users }}"
      - result
```

The second task then loops over the dictionary and the result from the previous task using a [`with_together`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-parallel-sets-of-data) loop which advances through the two data structures in step.

However, this looks like a less than ideal way to solve your problem.

If you look at what your tasks here are trying to do you could replace it more simply with something like this:

```
  - name: Add public keys to remote users QA
    authorized_key: user="{{ item.key }}" key="{{ lookup('file', '/opt/pubkeys/2016/q2/' + item.key ) }}"
    with_dict:
      - "{{ qa_users }}"
```

You can also remove the thid task where you cleared down the user's previous keys by simply using the `exclusive` parameter of the [authorized_keys](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html) module:

```
  - name: Add public keys to remote users QA
    authorized_key: user="{{ item.key }}" key="{{ lookup('file', '/opt/pubkeys/2016/q2/' + item.key ) }}" exclusive=yes
    with_dict:
      - "{{ qa_users }}"
```

Also, it might be a case of you trying to simplify things in an odd way for the question but your data structures you are using are less than ideal right now so I'd take a look at that if that's really what they look like.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and suggestion I probably will follow it, however I'm curious why I keep getting this error when running local_action:

- name: Find keys, ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, credentials/distribute-public-key.yml
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 41, column 17

- name: Find keys
    local_action:
                ^

Comment: @DmitryR you might want to try now with my edit. Didn't spot your initial issue with syntax around local_action. It's still untested mind so might still fail.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you @ydaetskcoR for sharing the right approach, the following solution did the dynamic public key distribution for me, when files residing on local machine and provisioned on remote EC2 machines:

```
---
- hosts: tag_Ansible_CLOUD_QA

  vars_files:
    - ../users/groups.yml
    - ../users/qa.yml
  remote_user: ec2-user
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:
  - name: Find user matching key files
    become_user: jenkins
    local_action: find paths="{{'/opt/pubkeys/2016/q1/'}}" patterns="{{ '*' + item.key + '*' }}"
    register: pub_key_files
    with_dict: "{{ qa_users }}"

  - name: Create groups
    group: name="{{ item.key }}" state=present
    with_dict: "{{ user_groups }}"

  - name: Allow test users to have passwordless sudo
    lineinfile: "dest=/etc/sudoers state=present regexp='^%{{ item.key }} ALL=.*ALL.* NOPASSWD: ALL' line='%{{ item.key }} ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL'"
    with_dict: "{{ user_groups }}"

  - name: Create remote users qa
    user: name="{{ item.key }}" comment="user" group=users groups="qa"
    with_dict: "{{ qa_users }}"

  - name: Add public keys to remote users qa
    #debug: "msg={{ 'User:' + item.item.key + '  KeyFile:' + item.files.0.path }}"
    authorized_key: user="{{ item.item.key }}" key="{{ lookup('file', item.files.0.path) }}" exclusive=yes
    with_items: "{{ pub_key_files.results }}"
```

This is the command line to get dynamic inventory based on EC2 Tags:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/ec2.py --private-key <path to your key file> --extra-vars '{"QUATER":"q1"}' credentials/distribute-public-key.yml
```

Comment: you should not answer as question... you comment on answer

Comment: @confiq There is a button answer your question which I used, and also you can't paste the code since the amount of characters is limited for comments and no line separation code highlighting, I assumed that anyone who looking for such solution will appreciate the answer that solves the case.